# woocommerce añadir stock a shortcode de productos por categoria

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesitaria un shortcode de este tipo, como el ejemplo siguiente, pero que muestre el stock de los productos:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" category="pantalones" cat_operator="IN"]
```

La idea sería tener algo asi, para que muestre el stock en la lista de productos:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" category="pantalones" cat_operator="IN" showstock="yes"]
```

He encontrado, esto, que funciona bien, e incluso muestra los productos que tienen mas stock que el que se indica, pero me falta que se muestre el stock cuando llamas al shortcode

```
add_shortcode( 'minimum_stock', 'minimum_stock_shortcode' );

function minimum_stock_shortcode( $atts ) {

global $woocommerce_loop;

// Attributes 
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
            'limit'         => '40',
            'columns'       => '5',
            'orderby'       => 'title',
            'order'         => 'asc',
            'category'      => '',
            'cat_operator'  => 'IN',
            'stock'         => '',
            ),
            $atts, 'minimum_stock'
        );

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'posts_per_page'        => $atts['limit'],
            'orderby'               => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'                 => $atts['order'],
            'meta_query'            => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => '_stock',
                    'value'         => $atts['stock'],
                    'compare'       => '>='
                )
            ),
            'tax_query'             => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                    'field'         => 'slug',
                    'terms'         => $atts['category'],
                )   
            )
        );


ob_start();

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>     

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

return '<div class="woocommerce">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

Creo que la cuesión, no es modificar el shortcode, sino la plantilla que usa para visualizar los datos, segun he buscado, el campo stock, solo es un campo en la base de datos, pero no se como editar dicha plantilla

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solucion, os la dejo por si alguien necesita:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_stock_shop', 10 );
  
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
   global $product;
   echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
}
```